# Problem when inserting multiple data ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-core

I am having trouble when inserting multiple records. When I try to insert 2 records the debugger shows the count of 2 but it only saves 1 record.

This is my code in my manager class

```
public void Create(IEnumerable<CollectionModel> p )
{
    collection module = new collection();
    foreach (var asa in p)
    {               
        module.AccountId = 1;
        module.Amount = asa.Amount;
        module.NameSou = asa.NameSou;
        module.Date = asa.Date;
        module.CreatedDatetime = DateTime.Now;
        module.UpdatedDatetime = DateTime.Now;

        _context.collection.Add(module);
    }
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Try adding `_context.collection.Add(module);` inside for loop

Comment: thank you for your help. I just edited my question. Its still saved 1 data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small Correction in your code. You are creating one module and updating the same every time. So it will always save the list of last item in your case list of last item of p.

```
 public void Create(IEnumerable<CollectionModel> p )
 {
   foreach (var asa in p)
     {   
       collection module = new collection();            
       module.AccountId = 1;
       module.Amount = asa.Amount;
       module.NameSou = asa.NameSou;
       module.Date = asa.Date;
       module.CreatedDatetime = DateTime.Now;
       module.UpdatedDatetime = DateTime.Now;

      _context.collection.Add(module);
    }
   _context.SaveChanges();
 }
```

Comment: Do i need to do a List or IEnumerable of `Collection Module`?

Comment: Sorry I din't get your question?

Comment: Do i need to make a ` List<collection> module = new List<collection>();` instead of `collection module = new collection();`?

Comment: No not list of collection just new collection, as foreach loop iterates every time, it will create a new instance of collection and it will be added to context collection.

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework offers two methods to insert records into database. `Add()` method allows to insert a single entity. `AddRange()` method inserts an IEnumerable collection. You can find more information from [here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework6/addrange-removerange.aspx).

Example:

```
 public void Create(IEnumerable<CollectionModel> args )
 {
    var modules = args.Select(asa=> new collection{
       AccountId = 1,
       Amount = asa.Amount,
       NameSou = asa.NameSou,
       Date = asa.Date,
       CreatedDatetime = DateTime.Now,
       UpdatedDatetime = DateTime.Now
      }).ToList(); 
    _context.collection.AddRange(modules);
   _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Is there any exception or the same result?

Comment: It works! Thank you! I just remove all the semi colon :) Thank you

Comment: hi @Ashiquzzaman just one more thine, if i want to add some data to other table, i will just do the same? right?

Comment: @PaulVincentDoroyan Yes. You can do. and one more suggestion please spend some time to read my provided link.

Comment: im getting 500 internal server error when I try to save 2 datas in two tables